# Branch.io initSession on Android returns null

Tags: android, branch.io

I can't Branch.io to initialize correctly on my Android app.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxx.xxxx.app"
android:versionCode="150"
android:versionName="2.8.1 (150)" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Branch.io values -->
    <!-- <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="true" /> -->
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="@string/branch_key" />
    <receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <activity
        android:name=".activities_fragments.CXMainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="@string/branch_uri_scheme" android:host="@string/branch_host" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

This is my main activity code:

```
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    if(!initiatedBranchDeepLinks) {
        // Configure Branch.io
        initiatedBranchDeepLinks = true;
        Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
        branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener(){
            @Override
            public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
                    // params will be empty if no data found
                    // ... insert custom logic here ...
                    String message = "Branch.io onInitFinished. Params: " + referringParams.toString();
                    Log.d(TAG, message);

                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, error.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
    }
}
```

I got a different app up and running on Android and they seem to be the same but for some reason, when I call branch.initSession(...), it returns a null.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a custom application class here?

Comment: I'm not.  Is that required.  I checked my other project (the one that works) and it does have a custom application.

Comment: (UPDATE) I put in a custom application with Branch.getAutoInstance(this) and I'M RUNNING!!! Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic! For reference, if you DO NOT have a custom application class, you can always use [this approach](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/advanced/android/#using-the-default-application-class) instead

Answer (score 0):

```
Branch.getAutoInstance(this) -> Branch.getAutoInstance(this, true)
Branch.getInstance(context) -> Branch.getInstance()
```

Do not call initSession when you have getAutoInstance()